# How to speed up mobile application which consumes a lot of API data?

Tags: android, api, performance

I built a social-type mobile Android application. Due to a specific requests, application contacts a remote API on almost each screen. Consequently, I feel that the app is slow.

What is the best design for apps like this? Should I have a special service which will handle all API requests and responses? If yes, users will not not see "data loading" information, but they still have to see the most accurate data refreshed from server side. How should I accomplish this?

Ideally, I would like to have the same UX like top apps where users simply press buttons and do stuff on the scree, and data is synched with the server-side without they know about it.

**NOTE:** I know how to do all this technically. I am asking about the best approach to this problem.

Comment: Are they hitting the same APIs for similar data on each screen?  If so, caching would probably greatly help.  So might pre-loading of data, requesting it ahead of time if its likely they'll need it.  Of course preloading is something that should be a setting, due to data caps.

Comment: Although I feel that the question is ambiguous, I would like to put my own thoughts about social platforms out.
In apps like Facebook or Instagram, I can see when they load up information from the API. They do heavy caching on the posts, so that when you open up the app, you would see some posts already popped up before they actually retrieve new ones from the API, which happens a few seconds later.
Also for actions like `Like` or `Comment` they alter the UI instantly and then send out the request asynchronously, and later update the UI if any update is needed. That's why there is no loading.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, the same API. Can you clarify "preloading" thing. I did not understand it. Not sure if it's due to my English or lack of my knowledge.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian Pls suggest if I can make this question less ambigious. What is not clear?

Comment: Preloading is requesting the information before you need it and storing it.  Lets say you're writing a web browser.  You may download the pages links lead to before the user clicks them, so you already have them downloaded when the user clicks the link, and just need to display them.

Comment: @sandalone I mean that it can depend on many factors. API response time, connection speed, application code, device power, ... All of them have to be fast to be able to build up a fast system.

Comment: About the `preloading` I agree with @Gabe. You can preload data that you think will be needed in the future and keep it in cache and use it if it's needed. However as Gabe mentioned, there should be an option for turning it off as some users may not want it because of limited data allowance. But personally, I don't think Facebook or Instagram do preloading..

Comment: @GabeSechan Where does preloading occur? A preloading service is started on app boot?

Comment: @MiroMarkarian Are you saying that these apps don't do global preloading but rate scree-limited preloading, or they don't preload things at all???

Comment: I think your comments lead me to conclusion that I need to open another questions, preloading-related. Since that may be the key.

Comment: @sandalone As we don't have access to their source codes, I can't surely tell if they do or not. However, if they did, it would be so data-intensive and they probably would have implemented an option to override that behavior. Also, in Instagram for instance, I don't see any apparent signs of preloading. They just load what is necessary as far as I think. However, it could be because of my inadequate knowledge of software engineering that I don't see the preloadings...

Comment: @MiroMarkarian I also don't think they do preloading but rather immediate changes with a background updating services. I say this with a large reserve.

Comment: @sandalone If I was you, I would integrate a profiler-like behavior in my code. For example you can log just before sending the request, log just after the response is received, and finally log once more after the information is processed and is shown to the user. That way you can measure that how much time the request has spent in various stages and what has took the most time and focus on optimizing that part. It can be the server that is slowing down the application.