# Should we implement content preloading in a mobile app (how to get Instagram-fast app)?

Tags: android, preloading

This is my first question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449767/how-to-speed-up-mobile-application-which-consumes-a-lot-of-api-data)) which lead me to conclusion that I need to open a better question.

Now, in order to have fast app like Instagram or other top social apps (IMHO Facebook Android app is not fast, but rather slow and outdated) is `preloading` the **best concept to use**?

If yes, then:

- Should preloding be a `service`?
- Where should this service be started? On app boot like splash screen?
- Will this `service` be in charge of syncing as well
- Should we have 1 global preload service or per-screen preloading services?